# postgresql empty string has length 1

Tags: postgresql

I have a column type text which looks like empty string but the length of it is 1.

the following sql

```sql
select 
teilnetz_name, 
length(teilnetz_name), 
trim(teilnetz_name), 
length(trim(teilnetz_name))
from test_table
```

results in

```sql
teilnetz_name| length| btrim| length
             |  1    |      | 1
```

and

```sql
select case when trim(teilnetz_name) is distinct from '' then true else false end 
from test_table

--return true

select case when teilnetz_name is distinct from null then true else false end
from test_table

--return true

select case when teilnetz_name is distinct from '' then true else false end
from test_table

--return true

select case when teilnetz_name is distinct from ' ' then true else false end
from test_table

--return true
```

How can I explain this phenomenon ?

I have on postgreql version 12.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column probably contains some other whitespace, e.g. a tab character. `trim()` will only remove **real** spaces.

Try

```
length(regexp_replace(teilnetz_name, '\s+', '', 'g'))
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be a non-printable unicode character in field `teilnetz_name`.
Try

```sql
select encode(teilnetz_name, 'hex') from test_table;
```

in order to see what `teilnetz_name` *actually* contains.